# How can i set default value to 0 if there is null in result in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to generate a query which generate ratio girls over boys.

For this i am using following query.

**SELECT (c_count_girls/c_count_boys) AS ratio FROM place WHERE placeId=1;**

It works fine. But whenever the values of c_count_girls=0 and c_count_boys=0

then this gives result like this :- **ratio=null**

but i want in this case the result should like this:- **ratio=0**

is any such type of solution there so i can set default ratio=0 if null is the result.

Please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE((c_count_girls/c_count_boys), 0) AS ratio
FROM place WHERE placeId=1;
```

[More Info about COALESCE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)

Comment: or IFNULL instead of COALESCE, although COALESCE the more standard way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

table-name-> gender ,,,,, table-columns->  gender_id , gender_type

SQL query:

```
select COALESCE(MAX(gender_id) , 0)+1 as max_gender_id_plus_one_fixed from gender
```

Output table:

**max_user_id_plus_one_fixed**

1